# Mysql GROUP_CONCAT is extremely slow

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I have a table in database with 450.000 rows.

Why is this query extremely slow? Can I fix it?

```
SELECT `ART_ARTICLE_NR`, `NAME`, `SUP_BRAND`, `PATH`, `CROSS_TYPE_NO`,
GROUP_CONCAT(`CATEG` ORDER BY `STR_LEVEL` ASC SEPARATOR '>>') AS CATEG2
FROM TOF_ARTICLES2
LIMIT 9
```

Comment: It's normally helpful to at least include the schema, and ideally some test data too.

Comment: what if you remove `ORDER BY STR_LEVEL` in `group_concat()`

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty - I really need that order

Comment: @AndySavage - Like I said before "I have 450.000 rows"

Comment: Looks like its doing full table scan, add an index if not done yet as `alter table TOF_ARTICLES2 add index STR_LEVE_idx(STR_LEVE)`

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty please give me an answear, I want to select your answear.Thank you very much!!!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? you are using GROUP_CONCAT without GROUP BY so it should do nothing. You are not selecting an actual group.

Comment: @BuduAdrian saying "450,000 rows" is neither your schema or some test data. With the schema in the question it would have been obvious if you were missing an index (which you seem to think fixed your query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its doing full table scan, add an index if not done yet as

`alter table TOF_ARTICLES2 add index STR_LEVE_idx(STR_LEVE)`